# How to make an interactive 2D grid in a window in python?

Tags: python

I want to test some algorithms on path-finding and want to create a window consisting of grids where I can drag my mouse while clicked to create walls and delete them with right click and drag. I just started with computer science and am fascinated with the algorithms however i don't know how to create the interactive window for it.

The example grid can be viewed here:
[A* pathfindind visualisation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=19h1g22hby8)

Comment: You could consider the use of tkinter, it allow to simply create simple GUI in python. A canvas binded to the event "onMouseClick" should be fine. Have fun.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here come a solution. You can use the list of list of cells objects contained in the CellGrid.grid object to apply your pathfinding algorithm on. Have fun.

```
from tkinter import *

class Cell():
    FILLED_COLOR_BG = "green"
    EMPTY_COLOR_BG = "white"
    FILLED_COLOR_BORDER = "green"
    EMPTY_COLOR_BORDER = "black"

    def __init__(self, master, x, y, size):
        """ Constructor of the object called by Cell(...) """
        self.master = master
        self.abs = x
        self.ord = y
        self.size= size
        self.fill= False

    def _switch(self):
        """ Switch if the cell is filled or not. """
        self.fill= not self.fill

    def draw(self):
        """ order to the cell to draw its representation on the canvas """
        if self.master != None :
            fill = Cell.FILLED_COLOR_BG
            outline = Cell.FILLED_COLOR_BORDER

            if not self.fill:
                fill = Cell.EMPTY_COLOR_BG
                outline = Cell.EMPTY_COLOR_BORDER

            xmin = self.abs * self.size
            xmax = xmin + self.size
            ymin = self.ord * self.size
            ymax = ymin + self.size

            self.master.create_rectangle(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, fill = fill, outline = outline)

class CellGrid(Canvas):
    def __init__(self,master, rowNumber, columnNumber, cellSize, *args, **kwargs):
        Canvas.__init__(self, master, width = cellSize * columnNumber , height = cellSize * rowNumber, *args, **kwargs)

        self.cellSize = cellSize

        self.grid = []
        for row in range(rowNumber):

            line = []
            for column in range(columnNumber):
                line.append(Cell(self, column, row, cellSize))

            self.grid.append(line)

        #memorize the cells that have been modified to avoid many switching of state during mouse motion.
        self.switched = []

        #bind click action
        self.bind("<Button-1>", self.handleMouseClick)  
        #bind moving while clicking
        self.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.handleMouseMotion)
        #bind release button action - clear the memory of midified cells.
        self.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", lambda event: self.switched.clear())

        self.draw()



    def draw(self):
        for row in self.grid:
            for cell in row:
                cell.draw()

    def _eventCoords(self, event):
        row = int(event.y / self.cellSize)
        column = int(event.x / self.cellSize)
        return row, column

    def handleMouseClick(self, event):
        row, column = self._eventCoords(event)
        cell = self.grid[row][column]
        cell._switch()
        cell.draw()
        #add the cell to the list of cell switched during the click
        self.switched.append(cell)

    def handleMouseMotion(self, event):
        row, column = self._eventCoords(event)
        cell = self.grid[row][column]

        if cell not in self.switched:
            cell._switch()
            cell.draw()
            self.switched.append(cell)


if __name__ == "__main__" :
    app = Tk()

    grid = CellGrid(app, 50, 50, 10)
    grid.pack()

    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I pasted the same. I had to replace tkinter with Tkinter (tkkinter with a lower case 't' doesn't work for some reason). I had an error like this:

  File "C:/Users/Pritam/PycharmProjects/RandomPythonProject/Randomfile.py", line 1, in <module>
    import Tkinter
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 38, in <module>
    import FixTk
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\FixTk.py", line 65, in <module>
    import _tkinter
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: I written this code using python 3 that's why there were case problem. For dll related problem, it seems that your python installation is broken... Can't help for this.